# How can I define the complexType in XML schema file?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define a "personinfo" type of my own so that other elements can refer to this complex type, but I got some validation errors. Can you teach me the right way to define "personinfo"? Is that caused by the namespace issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="xyz">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="enable" type="xs:boolean"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="employee" type="personinfo" />
        <xs:complexType name="personinfo">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: add validation errors to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move definition of personInfo type under xs:schema element, i.e. on the same level, as definition of xyz. Other constructions should be ok.

If your schema doesn't define target namespace (i.e. namespace into which defined elements and types belong) you haven't refer to your complex types with prefix in type attribute. But I think it is better to define target namespace (and corresponding prefix) and then you have to write it in qualified form, like type="myNs:personInfo".